# Best practice for submodules in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, structure, git-submodules

I have a project with this kind of structure:

```
-MyProject
--Package1
--Package2
--Package3
```

Each of "Package1"/"Package2"/"Package3" has its own package.json and dependencies.
What will be the best practice to import one of the submodules in another submodule (let's say I want to use some "Package2" functions on "Package1" code)? What will be the best solution for dev and what would be the best solution for prod?

I thought about maybe do a link between the dependent package but that I would still have a problem on prod.. Also, I'm not sure this would be the best solution for me..

I also thought about using lerna (https://github.com/lerna/lerna) but I don't want to publish my packages on npm (unless I have to) because they are private.

Thank you!

Comment: npm has options for private plans. It's very affordable. https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro

Comment: I know but I'm not looking for that kind of answer but a programatic one using free open-source packages or a specific project structure